# Send keypress END key to IFrame when Right arrow is clicked

Tags: jquery, iframe, keyup

I'm trying to trigger an keyup action for the END key in a iframe when the right arrow key is pressed.
I sounds not logical, I know, but I can't change it.

I cannot change the source of the Iframe and also I cannot change the key that is pressed. This is what I tried (but it isn't working):
Set the focus to the document
`$(document).focus();`

then bind key up event to the document

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == 39)
    {
        var press = jQuery.Event("keyup");
        press.ctrlKey = false;
        press.keyCode = 35;
        press.which = 35;

        var body = $('#player').contents();
        player.trigger(press);
    }
});
```

The IFrame has an id 'player'

I have no idea why it isn't working :-(

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The **Same Origin Policy** prevents scripted interaction between an Iframe and the parent page in the two domains do not match. This is there to prevent click-jacking and other mal-intent.